# Razor @Html.Raw(model.function())

Tags: c#, razor

I use this code in a view:

```
@section JavaScript{
...
    @Html.Raw(Model.LoadJavaScriptData())
...
}
```

LoadJavaScriptData() returns a String (JavaScript Code)

I've got already a view where this works, but with my new view it
doesn't load the whole String. At least Firebug shows me that.
Is it possible that the site finished loading before @Html.Raw function loaded
the String into the view?

I already checked the String of LoadJavaScriptData() when it returns.
It's correct.

I've got no clue what to do now.

Are there tools to load the site step by step? Especially can i go
through the cshtml step by step?

I use .NET MVC 3

Comment: When you render partial view, its sections are not loaded. You can verify that quite simply with debugger

Comment: thx, that's good to know
but i don't have any partitial views

Comment: For the last part of your question, have you tried using Page Inspector?  It's a feature in Visual Studio that's meant to help with scenarios like these.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh974728.aspx

Comment: I still don't know why it doesn't show me the whole code in Firebug. That's the reason why i thought my javascript code is broken, but i downloaded Google Chrome and it shows me the whole Javascript code.